# Can ASP.NET connect to WCF using net.tcp protocol?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, net.tcp

There is a WCF Windows Service listening in netTcpBinding protocol, which I understand is Microsoft's proprietary protocol (correct me if i am wrong). I need to write a website that will consume the WCF services. I know for certain PHP can only connect to WCF Service in SOAP (basicHttpBinding or wsHttpBinding) so I need to write another SOAP proxy.

[Some comments](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/ebc881de-1f5d-478a-adbb-042a003ffaff/)  on the internet suggest that it is possible to have ASP.NET website connect to a WCF Service via net.tcp protocol. Is this actually true? Where should I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding about the netTcpBinding is correct. It is proprietary and accessible only from .NET clients. Since ASP.NET is .NET you could consume your WCF service without any problems.

Comment: I guess then I can have *.php pages and *.aspx pages run side-by-side on IIS7.

Answer (score -1):

Ofcourse an ASP.NET web application can connect to a WCF service using net.tcp binding but not over the internet! If the application and the service arn't on the same server or in the same intranet it will not work, you have to choose a HTTP binding.

From my comment below:
Yes net.tcp can work over the internet but not every circumstances it's not recommended (check it at MSDN) to use it. Ofcourse if the whole server control is our we can give it a try but if not (the application and service hosted by a 3rd party member) the chances are not so high to get it work (for example port blocking, the net.Tcp listener is disabled, net.Tcp port sharing is not working or disabled)

Comment: "but over the internet!" -- can you kindly clarify this?

Comment: `If the application and the service arn't on the same server or in the same intranet it will not work` - this is a wrong statement! There's absolutely no problem consuming a WCF service exposing the netTcpBinding from anywhere (assuming of course a network route exists and no firewall is blocking the ports on which the WCF service is listening).

Comment: A have left to write 'not'. Yes net.tcp can work over the internet but not every circumstanses it's not recommended (check it at MSDN) to use it. Ofcourse if the whole server control is our we can give it a try but if not (the application and service hosted by a 3rd party member) the chances are not so high to get it work (for example port blocking, the net.Tcp listener is disabled, net.Tcp port sharing is not working or disabled).